# The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have `ASP.Net MVC` site.

Technology Stack

- ASP.Net 4.6
- C#.Net
- EF 6
- MySQL -Database

While I am trying to generate the database using `Nuget` command:-

```
Enable-Migrations -force
```

I am getting the below exception

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.

Following things are already **cross checked & tried** by me:-

- [The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception on a Sub Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801125/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-internal-appconfig-threw-an-except)
- [The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585611/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-internal-appconfig-threw-an-except)
- [Code First can't enable migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146280/code-first-cant-enable-migrations)

My App.Config:-

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="mydbContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;port=8080;database=mydb;uid=root;password=" />
</connectionStrings>



<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory,   MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
</providers>
```

Comment: What does the rest of your stack trace look like? And your config elements related to EF?

Comment: @rene I am getting this error in Nuget Package Manager Console

Comment: @rene added the rest config elements in the post

Comment: Shouldn't you use the MySql connection factory, instead of the SqlConnectionFactory? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20294903/578411

Comment: Try removing one of the `<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"` from the `providers` section. Also make here `name="mydbContext"`, `mydbContext` is the exact name of your class (case sensitive).

Comment: could be this is useful https://vnextcoder.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/mysql-net-entity-framework-code-first-migration/

Comment: @rene. I thought this could be the caused & corrected my config as per the link but it didn't

Comment: @IvanStoev. I tried what you said but it throws another error . `.The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded`

Comment: If you run `Enable-Migrations -force -Debug -Verbose` do you get a better (stack)trace?

Answer (score 6):

Have fixed it by making the **configSections** the first child of **configuration** in the config file.

```
<configuration>
```

...
...

Answer (score 6):

Just add **configSections** inside the **configuration** section if not added. And **configSections must be first child of configuration section** just like below code.

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString"
    connectionString="data source=20.20.1.1;initial catalog=myDB;user id=sa;password=123456;persist security info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
....
<!-- other configuration -->
....
</configuration>
```

Comment: That should be tag has the good answer. Thanks you!

Answer (score 5):

In Entity Framework `The type initializer` error is most likely due to malformed `Web.config` files, like having two or more sections of connection string, or having problem in the connection string itself, such as invalid provider.

Answer (score 3):

The type initialization error arises because the `invariantName=MySql.Data.MySqlClient` appears twice in the `<providers>` section of the `web.config` file.

Removing one of them (by commenting it out) solves the issue:

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Even I got this error while migrating. I had a data access layer(DAL) having my context class and web application referencing the data access layer. To migrate you have to add the connection string in the app.congig file of the DAL and also the web.config file in your web application. On removing the default connection string from the web.config file it worked for me.
Replace this

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-foo-20190108014329.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-foo-20190138014529;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

by

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="foo" connectionString="Data Source=foo; Initial Catalog=foo; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem.

My `app.config` was missing a section name in `configSections:`

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

I simply added it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyLocalDatabase" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I was getting errors similar to yours because of a wrong installation of the `MySql` connector client in my development machine. I installed `MySql` connector Nuget packages within Visual Studio, but it was not enough. I also needed to install `MySql` client which I downloaded from `MySql` website. After that the `Type` errors went away.

These are my Nuget packages:
[image]

And this is [the download page of MySql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) which I downloaded and installed manually.

Note: the `defaultConnectionFactory` value is never used if you specify explicitly the type of your provider. In that case it doesn't matter which value you have in the configuration file in this setting. See point 3 in [this reference doc page in MySql website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html).

I recommend you to check if your `MySql` is correctly installed in your machine by using MySql command line client console. Try to connect to the server from outside Visual Studio with your connection string values.

Comment: Step 1 >> `Install-Package MySQL.Data.Entities` 

Step 2 >> `Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.8.8`

Step 3 >>  `Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.8.8`

Comment: I didn't install those packages you say, I installed the ones I show in the screencap: in the "Manage Nuget Packages" wizard in Visual Studio I selected the package MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity, the other package was installed as a dependency of this one. And after that I installed manually the MySql connector from outside Visual Studio.I was getting the same error as you until I did that last step.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the connection string and add the migration again. Connection string will be added automatically. I am having the same issue and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

***I had these same issue... Check Root Web.config (Fixed)***

- **1-** Check the configSections is first child
- **2** Remove the Extra connection strings you have (Comment them out) Stay with the one you want.

**Note:** *I was reading leeNaylors book(asp.net mvc with entity f...) according to his book this should´not be an issue, having more than 1 Connection string... but it turns out it does matter for migrations.
[web.config][image]*

Thumbs up if my answered helped you...

[Web.config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cs7Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I realised that  entityframework was not declared in config file.

So I added

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

above the  connection string

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-ABHI;Initial Catalog=IdentityDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

First check the connection string in the web.config file.

If you have two connection strings then comment the second connection string.

Comment: Duplicates this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62691410/861716. And in fact all the answers about connection strings. "check the connection string" isn't really meaningful and OP doesn't have two connection strings.