# Type is not resolved for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.8.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have `ASP.Net MVC` site where I am using `MySql`as database with `Entity Framework`

When running the following command on Nuget Package Manager Console

```
Enable-Migrations -force
```

Getting the error

> Type is not resolved for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.8.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'

Here is how my Web.Config looks like.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="mb_databaseContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\localhost;port=8080;database=myDb;uid=root;password=" /></connectionStrings>

 <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
</providers>
```

Please note MySql is running as

## localhost:8080/phpmyadmin

Comment: Make sure you installed correctly the Nuget packages for MySql.ConnectorNET. If you did, try unistalling and installing them again. If that also fails, download and install the latest version of the connector from MySQL web site, running the installer from outside Visual Studio. That last step fixed that error for me. I included the links [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40574224/1182515).

Answer (score 3):

Solution

You probably need to install the MySql connector, I did that and it worked.
[Download Connector/Net](http://Http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)